# How to make an intellisense for array type json in ACE.js editor?

Tags: javascript, json, autocomplete, ace-editor

I have been using Ace.js for my javascript editor. i created a js file to make my ace editor for autocompleter.

MyJs File for autoCompleter:

```
var editorDefinitions = {
    "!name": "myeditor",
    "profilVerileri":
      [{ "test": "fsdf", "id": "1" }, { "test": "fsdf", "id": "2" }, { "test": "dasd", "id": "3" }],
```

But my autocompleter for arrays does not work. Look below :

[image]

if you look at my desired autocompleter :

[image]
"test" should be autocompleted after press dot " profilVerileri[i]."

My entire Code are :

```
  var defs = [editorDefinitions];
    var ternServer = new TernServer({
      defs: defs
    });

    editor.ternTooltip = new TernTooltip(editor, ternServer);
    LangTools.addCompleter(ternServer);
    editor.setOptions({
        enableBasicAutocompletion: true
    });
    editor.focus();
```

Comment: Please check your title: "[IntelliSense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense)" is a Microsoft product, while Ace is a Mozilla product. You may name it "[Code completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_code_completion)" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to turn on live autocompletion

```
      editor.setOptions({
        enableBasicAutocompletion: true,      
        enableLiveAutocompletion: true,
      });
```